# Can't use hooks in local dependency

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, dependencies

I have 3 local React projects

1. My UI project which has (2) and (3) as dependencies
2. My project which contains an exported module, which has (3) as a dependency
3. My component library and context holder

All projects are on React 18.

The problem I am facing is that when (2) is using a component from (3) that uses a hook such as `useEffect` I am getting the error:

[image]

And a subsequent error message states that the error stems from the component in (3) that I'm using within (2).

This can be seen to be the case by removing the `useEffect` hook within the component in (3) and re-building everything again, as I can now get the correct output in the browser:

[image]

**Project 1**

```
const App = () => (
    <>
      <h1>Project 1 child added to module from project 2</h1>
      <Project2Module/>
    </>
);
```

**Project 2**

```
export const Project2Module = (props) => (
    <>
        <h1>Project 2 child added to component from project 3</h1>
        <Project3Component />
    </>
)
```

**Project 3**

```
export const Project3Component = (props) => {
    // Comment out this useEffect and it will render, include it and it will error
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('Inside project 3 component');
    }, []);

    return (<h1>Project 3 child</h1>);
}
```

I have read all over the web about removing `react` and react-dom`from the`dependencies`and`devDependencies`and only keeping them within`peerDependencies`within the`package.json`on projects we wish to include, to which I have done for both`project 2`and`project 3`.

Since projects **2** and **3** these are under development, I have been building them locally and the including the dependancies by all forms of inclusion such as `yalc`, `npm link <project_name>`, `npx link <local_path_to_project>` and `npm i --no-save <local_path_to_project>`.

I cannot think of anything else I can possibly do to get this work...
When considering the error message:

1. Mismatching version of React - I have made sure that each project has `React` and `React-dom` being on the same version of 18.
2. Breaking rules of Hooks - I'm certain this is not the case from each project's perspective.
3. Might have more than one copy of react - I was hoping this is what `npx link` and `npm i --no-save` would have solved, along with only keeping `react` and `react-dom` within the `peerDependencies` of the sub-dependancies...

Answer (score 1):

I found that the suggestions in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72413194/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-properties-of-null-reading-usecontext) helped me out immensely!

Essentially what I had been doing is running `npm install` on each of my projects such that I could build them locally as I was referencing the `/dist` versions of components/modules etc.

It seems that `npm link` would bring the `node_modules` folder of the linked project in, and doing this multiple times across different projects it must have compiled them all into one big one, which means there would be 3 different `react` and `react-dom` versions as it suggested in the error message.

To solve this, I deleted `react` and `react-dom` from the node_modules from the subdependencies and then re-built.

The solve was actually quite simple. It's just a shame there wasn't much to tell you how this could happen.