# How to fix "cannot read property 'useState' of null" within react-navigation package

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I built an app in react-native using the basic `NavigationContainer` of `@react-navigation/native`.
Everything was working fine until I decided to switch to the Tab navigation system of that same package.

The code below produces an error "Cannot read property 'useState' of null", apparently coming from the package itself.

Here is the simple code

```js
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

const Test = () => (
  <View>
    <Text>Test</Text>
  </View>
);

const AppNavigation = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Tab.Navigator>
        <Tab.Screen
          name="Home"
          component={Test}
        />
      </Tab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};

export default AppNavigation;
```

And here is the stacktrace

```
ERROR  TypeError: Cannot read property 'useState' of null

This error is located at:
    in BottomTabNavigator (created by AppNavigation)
    in EnsureSingleNavigator
    in BaseNavigationContainer
    in ThemeProvider
    in NavigationContainerInner (created by AppNavigation)
    in AppNavigation (created by AppBase)
    in ErrorBoundary (created by AppBase)
    in ThemeProvider (created by AppBase)
    in Unknown (created by AppBase)
    in QueryClientProvider (created by AppBase)
    in AppBase (created by RootApp)
    in ReactNativeProfiler (created by RootApp)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by __Sentry.TouchEventBoundary)
    in __Sentry.TouchEventBoundary (created by RootApp)
    in RootApp
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in AppContainer
    in Mobile(RootComponent), js engine: hermes
```

Thanks by advance

I expected this small piece of code to work fine on itself since I'm using the last versions of the packages.

Comment: Do you have multiple packages installed at different levels? See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73981865/3982562)